# get AVG() after GROUP BY in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I just start to learn MYSQL and meet a problem like this

So the table is like this:

```
id  name  moneySpent 
1   Alex    3
2   Alex    1
3   Bill    4
4   Alex    2
5   Alex    1
6   Chris   5
7   Chris   3
```

Lets say I wanna know the Average money spent per person. I try to do that by using SUM() GROUP BY and AVG() but I got stuck at AVG()

```
SELECT name, sum(moneySpent) AS total FROM table GROUP BY name;
```

then this will return

```
name  total
Alex  7
Bill  4
Chris 8
```

Then how can I get a (7+4+8)/3 using AVG()?

Comment: `... union all select 'average', SUM(moneySpent) / count(distinct name) from table`

Answer (score 7):

You can get average per person using:

```
SELECT AVG(total) AS AVERAGE 
FROM (SELECT name, sum(moneySpent) AS total 
      FROM table GROUP BY name) A
    ;
```

Output:

```
AVERAGE
6,3333
```

Comment: So this is like I use a table to store the first SELECT result and do AVG() on this new table? Thanks for your answer but I wonder if I can do this avoid additional space? Don't blame me if I got this wrong please I just start learning SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inner query to get `sum` and outer query to derive `average` from sum as below.

```
SELECT  Avg(sum1) FROM  (
SELECT  Sum(amount) AS sum1
FROM table1
GROUP BY NAME
) T1
```

It will generate below output.

```
AVERAGE_AMOUNT_SPENT
------------------
6.3333
```

which is what you want to be the output i.e. `(7+4+8)/3 = 6.333`

You can check demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f85ded7/2)

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 ways to do this, first is use a new table to store the SELECT result. It is much more esay but may take more space.
Second is by jarlh, It comes to me that I do not need to GROUP BY the whole table, I can just add all moneySpent up and divided by distinct name count.
Thanks people!

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(total) as average from (SELECT name, sum(moneySpent) AS total FROM table GROUP BY name);
```

You can use this query to get your desired output

`OUTPUT:
AVERAGE
6.3333333333333333`