# Get SUM() after GROUP BY

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sum

So I have a table name "sumTable"

| year | Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 1996-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 1996-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 1997-10-08 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 1996-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 5 |
| 1994-11-05 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 1996-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 1999-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 1996-10-08 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 1995-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 5 |
| 1996-11-05 00:00:00.000 | 1 |

I want to know the total number of orders in "1996" and to be displayed in a single column,

```
Expected Output 
Total Orders
14
```

I tried using this

```
select datepart(yy, '1996'), sum(orders) AS 'Total_Orders' from SumTable group by orders
```

and this link too
[get AVG() after GROUP BY in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811265/get-avg-after-group-by-in-mysql)

Please advice a solution!

Comment: Use a  `WHERE` clause, if you only want to consider certain rows (those of 1996 in your case).

Comment: What do you believe the constant value `datepart(yy, '1996')` is meant to be doing?  If you want just one output row, why are you grouping by the orders column *(which will return a separate output row for each distinct value in that column)*?

Comment: @MatBailie, I am learning SQL and that is my assignment requirement to group by orders column.
With the datepart function I was trying to filter the year, as you can see the date format is different in my table.

Comment: Just take the sum of all orders in 1996 (>= 1/1/1996 and < 1/1/1997) w/o `GROUPBY`. Using `WHERE` should be considered a basic skill when starting with SQL.

Comment: On a side note: Don't use single quotes for alias names. They are meant for string literals, and you can get unexpected results sometimes when confusing the two. In your case, why use delimiters at all? Just do `SUM(orders) AS total_orders`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your requirement you want a single row for the sum of all qualifying rows - you are not grouping anything so there is no need for `group by`.

```
Select sum (Orders) as Total_orders
from SumTable
where [year] >='19960101' and [year] < '19970101';
```

You would want *groups* of aggregated values if for example you wanted each *year* and its sum of orders.

```
Select year([year]) as Order_year, sum(Orders) as Total_orders
from SumTable
group by year([year])
order by Order_year;
```

Although it's technically okay to have a column named *year*, it's actually not a year but an Order *Date* so makes for a somewhat confusing query, I would consider a more meaningful name; this also assumes column *year* is a *datetime* data type.